# Open Source Camera app with easy to use panorama mode

Tags: android, open-source, photography

I'm looking for a camera app on Android which should have a decent, easy to use panorama mode. My current main driver is [Open Camera](https://f-droid.org/packages/net.sourceforge.opencamera/), but I never managed to create a panorama photo with it. The camera that shipped with my BQ Aquaris ([BQ Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bq.camerabq)) does this excellently and easy (press the knob, then just move the device slowly, press again when done), but is not open source and further wasn't updated for quite a while (since 6/2019). To sum up:

- for Android
- must be open source, ideally available at F-Droid (if it's open source, the second part I could take care for), but must at least be available outside the walled gardens (so not only at Play Store, Amazon etc.)
- supports an easy-to-use panorama mode (in the sense of creating an "ultra-wide landscape picture", like stitching 3..5 landscape photos next to each other)

Being the one used to turn up apps (e.g. for my app listings, or my app repo) I'm afraid I'm asking a quite difficult thing here – so I'm looking forward to be proven wrong and seeing such an app exists, so I can use it :)

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with Open Camera before but I decided to give the latest another shot and after 10 minutes of persistence I managed to figure it out.

What you need to do is

- Click the 3 dots menu,
- Set Photo Mode to PANO.
- Then in portrait orientation, starting with one side of the scene you want to capture (lets say left side for example), press the blue camera button to start.
- Then rotate the camera to the right to line up with the blue circle as perfectly as possible, if you see a white rotation arrow appear, this means you need to adjust the TILT of the camera in the direction of the arrow while keeping the blue circle in the right place.
- When you do that correctly the blue circle will satisfyingly "pop" and a new one will appear to the right.
- Repeat the process till you get the whole pano, then press the big white tick.

It actually works quite well and it gives you more control than the easy pano you get in mainstream phones, but it takes some practice to make it work.  After practice it gets easy and satisfying, and I suspect the image you get from this method is actually better than the normal easy pano from most phones, because it forces you to line up the image exactly.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I know that. It's still much trickier than with e.g. the default camera app coming with Lineage, where I can use either portrait or landscape and just slide, no need to "pop circles". And yes, I also retried recently and had more success than in the past, but it's still unsatisfying (I certainly wouldn't call it "easy and satisfying"). But good you described it step-by-step as there are certainly more folks outside struggling with it…

Comment: Oh which is the app that comes with Lineage? I have Lineage 19.1 and the default camera app is so basic, only photo, video, and HDR

Comment: They switched it with 19 or 20. I referred to the old one. Yes, it's pretty basic – but it works well for panorama (which is all I use it for – for everything else I use Open Camera for years now). LOS switched to Aperture. I haven't tested that yet as that update didn't yet arrive here.